# Proposition 8.41 of Fulton and Harris: A First Course in Representation Theory. Is this step actually simple?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am curious about this remark in the proof; they have just assumed that a connected Lie group $G$ can be assumed to be a matrix Lie group, and justify it like this:

> This is a harmless assumption, given the statement (to be proved in
> Appendix E) that any finite-dimensional Lie algebra may be embedded in
> the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n\mathbb{R}$: the subgroup of
> $\mathbf{GL}_n \mathbb{R}$ generated by $\mathrm{exp}(\mathfrak{g})$ will be a
> group isogenous to G [...]

I cannot see any other way of giving this isogeny than by using the existence of a Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula for non-matrix Lie groups. Given this is never mentioned in the book and from what I can tell requires some effort.

I hope I'm missing something, since it would be nice to only have to prove the existence of BCH in the matrix exponential context.

Comment: I don't think you need any BCH formula here. The comment shows that there is a matrix group $G$ with that Lie algebra. Then you can take the universal cover $\tilde{G}$ which is simply connected and thus unique and so every other Lie group with the same Lie algebra has this as a universal cover as well. Therefore they are all quotients of $\tilde{G}$, indeed they are all isogenous to it. They are not necessarily isogenous to $G$, in point of fact, but this is fine as we can go to $\tilde{G}$ first and then to the other group.

Comment: I believe this uniqueness is meant to follow from what they call "The Second Principle", which (at least in the book) is a logical consequence of Prop. 8.41. Maybe I'm missing an easier way to see that there is a unique simply connected model of a Lie algebra. @Callum

Comment: Ah yes you are right. Sometimes it is difficult in Fulton and Harris to see where they actually prove a fact. I would indeed use what they call the Second Principle (and I would call the homomorphisms theorem) to prove that but the cart is now firmly before the horse. I think that may actually need the BCH formula after all but there is a good sketch of that proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group%E2%80%93Lie_algebra_correspondence#Proof_of_the_homomorphisms_theorem)

Comment: (Not really an answer, but useful to me and maybe someone else who stumbles across this question) After looking around a bit, there is a direct proof of the proposition by integrating over the distribution of the Lie subalgebra much as one integrates over the vector field of an element of a Lie algebra. This seems to work for the same reasons the BCH should intuitively exist, but is more directly conceptual in my view. The key result is [Frobenius's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28differential_topology%29)